# How to use quotes with powershell command line, get-wmiobject, and query or filter

Tags: powershell

My command and the error I get are below. I've tried every combination of quotes, braces, and backticks I can think of. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None -Command " & {(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "name='MSSQLSERVER'").StartName}"
```

> Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from win32_service where
>   name=MSSQLSERVER" At line:1 char:6
>   +  & {(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter  name=MSSQLSERVER).StartName}
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the windows batch, you need to escape the ( and ) characters using the ^.
In Powershell, you need to escape the single quote using the backquote to ensure it gets passed on to wmi. (I left out the call operator etc, I think you don't need those).

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -InputFormat None ^
    -Command ^(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "name=`'MSSQLSERVER`'"^).StartName
```

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for helping me.  I've spent hours on this so far.  I ran that and got this result:

 `Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select ^ from win32_service where name='MSSQLSERVER'"`

Another problem I would have with this solution if it worked is that I'm calling actually calling powershell through the powershell_out function in Chef, and it encloses the -Command parameter in double quotes like this

`-Command " <stuff I put in>"`

So I don't have control over those quotes, and they are just contributing to the quoting problem.

Comment: This ended up working for me: `(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "name=\`'MSSQLSERVER\`'").StartName`.  Thank you! I couldn't have done it without you.